# Insert but i need 2 cursors synchronized

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

basically my problem is:
I have two queries where i need to take data for an insert.

Example:

I have a table with a column (name) that has a certain data
and another one with the same data(name_domain) plus other specific data i need.

So i need 2 cursors;

1. select name from x where name is not null; --> cursor_name.
2. select date,name_domain,address,surname from y where name_domain = cursor_name; --> cursor_data.

so in the insert the values will be replaced with cursor_data(%rowtype variable).1,2,3,4,5 data.

I've just tried with parametric cursor but i am not that good at it, but i am sure that with that its easy.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  You may not need cursors at all.

Comment: Two cursors are doable. But can you consider joining the two selects in a way that you only need one cursor? (Then you possibly can merge it into the insert, and won't need pl/sql at all.)

Comment: I echo what 9000 said; this sounds very much like all you need is a join in your select statement that you can then use in you insert statement, e.g. `insert into ... select ... from x inner join y on x.name = y.name_domain`

Comment: Guys, thanks, i only arrived to the JOIN after 3 fails ... But yes, with a left join i solved it.